# PCL include files

Tags: ros, pcl, package, rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

i am very new to the ROS-Package. I tried to understand the tutorials but i have some trouble.

I want to use the example code http://www.ros.org/wiki/pcl/Tutorials Example 5.2 and modifiy it, so it will use my piont cloud generateted by a kinect.

However, the problem is that if i run cmake the following error appears: "fatal error: pcl/range_image/range_image.h: No such file or directory"

So i tried to build a ROS pcl backage by following the tutorials. The problem remains. I'm really sure about, that i am doing something completly wrong.

So: How do I build a pcl package and use it in my own code?

Thanks for the help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9322/pcl-include-files/) by [SLAMnect](https://answers.ros.org/users/253/slamnect/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2011-03-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you add pcl as a dependency in manifest.xml?

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're new to ROS please go through the [Start Guide](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/StartGuide) so you understand the concepts of ROS packages etc.  The PCL tutorials assume that you are familiar with these concepts.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-03-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I agree with Tully that you should read through the tutorials for ROS. What you'll probably  find is that you haven't put a dependency in your package manifest for pcl -- which is why you can't find the header file.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-03-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

yes, thats my problem. I figuered it out yesterday. But you both are right. I should go through the ROS tutorials. Thanks for the help.

---

Originally posted by [SLAMnect](https://answers.ros.org/users/253/slamnect/) with karma: 58 on 2011-03-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1